# Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?)

Tags: angular

Can anyone please help with this error. I am trying to test this component but getting the following error. I have also added MatDialogRef to providers but still no luck.

**confirmation-popup.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirmation-popup',
  templateUrl: './confirmation-popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirmation-popup.component.scss']
})
export class ConfirmationPopupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmationPopupComponent>, @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.data)
  }

  
  closeYesModel() {
    this.dialogRef.close('Yes');
  }

    
  closeNoModel() {
    this.dialogRef.close('NO');
  }

  closeModel(){
    this.dialogRef.close('NO');
  }


}
```

In this spec file I have added required things in providers

**confirmation-popup.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { ConfirmationPopupComponent } from './confirmation-popup.component';

describe('ConfirmationPopupComponent', () => {
  let component: ConfirmationPopupComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ConfirmationPopupComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ ConfirmationPopupComponent ],
        imports: [RouterTestingModule,
                  MatDialogModule],
         providers: [{
          provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
          useValue: {hasBackdrop: false}},
          MatDialogRef],

    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConfirmationPopupComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This is the error I am facing

**Error message**

```
ConfirmationPopupComponent > should create
Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?).
error properties: Object({ code: 204 })
Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?).
    at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11501:1)
    at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11491:1)
    at providerToFactory (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11534:1)
    at providerToRecord (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11521:1)
    at R3Injector.processProvider (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11424:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11410:1
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:4162:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepForEach (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:4162:1)
    at R3Injector.processInjectorType (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:11410:1)
Expected undefined to be truthy.
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/shared/components/confirmation-popup/confirmation-popup.component.spec.ts:32:23)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:1)
```

Comment: I guess you could simply mock dialogRef.close?

Comment: could you please show how to mock that??- @MikeOne